# How to send automatically a request when internet is available in Android

Tags: php, android

I need to make some request to a server(an http request to a php page).I want that user can send a post even if internet isn't available and when it will be available the app must send all unsend post from users like viber or whatapps. I don't have any idea to do this and i need your help.

Comment: implement in a broadcast receiver that listen for the connectivity events the answer bellow

Comment: Thanck you @Buda Gravil but i make it. My problem is that i don't have a system to send the posts when internet is available. I think to save all unsend post in a file and i try to send them if net is available and also delete this post from the file. But i want to know if there are other method to do this

Answer (score 1):

You can use this way to check whether `Internet` is working or not

```
public class InternetConnection {

    // CHECK FOR INTERNET METHOD
    public static final boolean isInternetOn(Context ctx) {

        boolean isInternetOn = false;
        ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager) ctx
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        final android.net.NetworkInfo wifi = connMgr
                .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
        final android.net.NetworkInfo mobile = connMgr
                .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
        TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) ctx
                .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

        if (wifi.isAvailable()&&wifi.isConnected()) {

            isInternetOn = true;
        }
        // gets the current TelephonyManager
        else if (tm.getSimState() != TelephonyManager.SIM_STATE_ABSENT) {

            // the phone has a sim card
            if (mobile != null) {

                boolean mobileDataEnabled = false; // Assume disabled
                ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) ctx
                        .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                try {
                    Class<?> cmClass = Class.forName(cm.getClass().getName());
                    Method method = cmClass
                            .getDeclaredMethod("getMobileDataEnabled");
                    method.setAccessible(true);
                    mobileDataEnabled = (Boolean) method.invoke(cm);
                    if (mobileDataEnabled) {
                        isInternetOn = true;
                    }
                } catch (Exception e)
                {

                    Log.e("Error", e+"");
                }
                return isInternetOn;

            } else {
                isInternetOn = false;
            }
        } else {
            // no sim card available
            isInternetOn = false;
        }

        return isInternetOn;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you but my problem is that i don't have any system to resend the unsend post. for exemple save them in an file et resend after. Or if there other methods to do this